# How to dynamically hide normal fieldset (or) Non tab fieldset in ui component?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, ui-form

I created a custom admin form using Ui component. In that form i need to show and hide a fieldset dynamically based on a condition. I tried to add class for that fieldset, But the class not working in Normal Fieldset or Non tab fieldset.

```
<fieldset name="menu_items" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\CustomFieldset">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label>Menu Items</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
        <fieldset name="assign_applicants">
            <settings>
                <label>Menu Items</label>
                <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            </settings>

            <field name="name" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">menu</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <dataType>string</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Name</label>
                    <dataScope>name</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
```

Here I need to dynamically hide the `menu_items` fieldset. So I created a class as `CustomFieldset`

The `CustomFieldset` class is:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\ComponentVisibilityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class CustomFieldset extends Fieldset implements ComponentVisibilityInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;

        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    //This method is responsible for show and hide the fieldset

    public function isComponentVisible(): bool
    {
        $visible = 0; // For now Hide the fieldset statically, later write the logics here
        return (bool)$visible;
    }
}
```

This class is working only the `menu_items` fieldset is on tab format. Whenever I tried to add class for (non tab) Normal fieldset, the class not working. So in this case how i dynamically hide the fieldset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `CustomFieldset` class, overrides `prepare` function rather than `isComponentVisible`, the code should look like:

```
    public function prepare() {
        $visiable = // do some work to get boolean value;
        $config = $this->getData('config');
        $config['visible'] = $visiable;
        $this->setData('config', $config);
        parent::prepare();
    }
```

and then remove `implements ComponentVisibilityInterface` and the function `isComponentVisible`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to hide the fieldset based on condition.

**Step 1:** Override prepare method of your fieldset like below.

> Your Form.xml

```
<fieldset name="menu_items" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\CustomFieldset">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label>Menu Items</label>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </settings>
    <fieldset name="assign_applicants">
        <settings>
            <label>Menu Items</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        </settings>

        <field name="name" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">menu</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

> Prepare method of your component fieldset class CustomFieldset.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\ComponentVisibilityInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

/**
 * Class Fieldset
 * @package VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form
 */
class CustomFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    /**
     * @var \VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * RuleInformationFieldset constructor.
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     * @param \VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        \VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * hide or show fieldset based on module enabled or disabled.
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        $visiable = false;
        $config = $this->getData('config');

        if( $this->helper->isModuleEnable() ) {
            $visiable = true;
        }

        $config['visible'] = $visiable;
        $this->setData('config', $config);
        
        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** You need to disable the whole fieldset then add the following code in your Data provider class.

```
/**
 * Get meta function.
 * return mixed
 */
public function getMeta()
{
    $meta = parent::getMeta();

    if($this->helper->isModuleEnable()) {

        $meta['menu_items']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 1;
    } else{
        $meta['menu_items']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 0;

    }
    return $meta;
}
```

I hope it will help you or other.